# How do I position a more_vert icon in flutter at right top corner without scaffold and directly into MaterialApp?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I don't need a AppBar widget, I directly want to add a menu bar at top right corner
I tried using Positioned element but I wonder if there is a efficient way. AppBar contains option for menu item, but I have MaterialApp without any need of AppBar.

Comment: Please show your code and maybe an image to demonstrate what the issue is. I'm assuming you need to place it in a SafeZone widget to avoid top bar overriding

Comment: I meant `SafeArea`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.